# Test to see if the date today is between a date and month

Tags: php

I would like to test to see if the date today is within the range of `rangeBegin` and `rangeEnd`.
Currently the code below returns false. Using `echo $today` results in the value being 17/12 which is correct for the value of `today`

```
   <?php
    $today = date('d.m');
    $today= date('d/m', strtotime($today));; 
        $rangeBegin = strtotime("01-12");
        $rangeEnd =  strtotime("02-01");

        if($rangeBegin <= $today && $rangeEnd >= $today)
        {
          //in range
        }
        else
        {
          //not in range
        }
    ?>
```

Please could someone advise me where I have gone wrong in the above code in order to test to see if the date today is between the two ranges.

I.E. as it is the 17th Dec, it should return true as it is between 1st Dec and 2nd Jan.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you please clarify what you are asking?

Comment: Thank you, have done so in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that 2 january is next year. And strtotime doesn't work like that.

```
$today = new DateTime();
$year = (int) $today->format("Y");
$rangeBegin = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "$year-12-01 00:00:00");
$rangeEnd = clone $rangeBegin;
$rangeEnd =  $rangeEnd->modify("+32 days");

if ($rangeBegin <= $today && $rangeEnd >= $today) {
  echo "true";
} else {
  echo "false";
}
```

Set the correct time zone somewhere.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Oslo");
```